# swift layoutIfNeeded creates afterimages

Tags: ios, swift

[example GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEL22.jpg)

I made the CollectionView resizing animation and the CollectionViewCell resizing animation run at the same time.

This code is a CollectionView resizing animation.

```swift
    private func changeCollectionViewHeight(toMode: DisplayMode, duration: TimeInterval) {
        let toBottomConstant: CGFloat
        let toCollectionViewHeight: CGFloat
        switch toMode {
        case .big:
            toBottomConstant = 0
            toCollectionViewHeight = 818
        case .small:
            toBottomConstant = 200
            toCollectionViewHeight = 618
        }

        // this is collection view constraints
        self.bottomConstraints.constant = toBottomConstant
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

This code is a CollectionView Cell resizing animation.

```swift
class TransitionManager: NSObject {
...
    func updateTransitionWithAnimation(duration: TimeInterval) {
        self.duration = duration
        startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(updateTransitionProgress))
        updater.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: .common)
    }

    func updateTransition(progress: Double) {
        transitionLayout.transitionProgress = CGFloat(progress)

        transitionLayout.invalidateLayout()
        if progress == finishTransitionValue {
            collectionView.finishInteractiveTransition()
            updater.invalidate()
        }
    }

}
// TransitionLayout.swift
final class TransitionLayout: UICollectionViewTransitionLayout {
...

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
        if let layoutAttributes = attributes as? TestCollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
            layoutAttributes.transitionProgress = transitionProgress
            if let nextLayoutAttributes = nextLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) as? TestCollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
                layoutAttributes.nextLayoutCellFrame = nextLayoutAttributes.frame
            }
        }

        return attributes
    }
...
}
```

Cells are animated by calculating frames using CADisplayLink.